# Associating two variables in XGBoost model

Tags: predictive-modeling, data-cleaning

I am trying to build a model that will predict a college football players probability of being drafted. I have multiple variables with different athletic measurements, but for the sake of example lets just say I'm looking at 40-yard dash time and vertical jump height. I also have the grade(freshman, sophomore, junior, senior) of the athletes at the time their 40-yard dash and jump height were measured. The grade is important because it tells you how much more time a player has to improve before the draft, a player's performance generally improves over the four years of college and measurements taken early in the college career are less informative about their draft performance than measurements taken their senior year.  I want my model to be able to reflect that. Is there a way to "link" the measurements to the time they were measured? Is this even necessary? My worry is that with about 20 columns of measurements and 20 columns of grades, the model might associate the wrong grade and measurement columns.